# Uploading multipart file with REST API and calculating hash

Tags: spring, rest, file, upload, multipart

I have a code that downloads files, then calculates the hashes (md5 and sha256) and saves the hash in the database. Everything works fine, but generates "junk files". I don’t know where they come from. Does Spring boot generate them or Intellij Idea or something else.  Just somebody tell me how to call them. [image]

Comment: Show your Service’s save method. It looks like these are the uuids for file names. Have you tried to open these files in their native app(s)?

Comment: Sorry for being late for an answer. They are littering my directory I don't know how do deal with them. This is my service class.
https://gist.github.com/ilkin-ismailov/f87df78ee1e723142c96fba76b508b54

Comment: Delete all these not reqd files then Try commenting line #73 in ur service. Looks like you dont need that piece of code(method). I havnt tried but looks like that is causing creating those files.

Comment: Ah..I guessed it right initially. Line #96 where you are calling createTempfile, that is creating the file with UUID as name. Check around that and fix accordingly.